# Manipulate array of parent controller from child controller inside ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to manipulate items in an array stored in a parent controller. When I manipulate the items, I want to do this from within an ng-repeat loop inside a child controller.

As far as I can tell, the array in the parent controller is being updated - in fact `s===cs`. I have read that `$scope.$apply()` might be the answer but I'm not sure how to call that using the "`controller as`" syntax below - or if that is even wise.

```
<html ng-app='app'>
<body ng-controller='parent_controller as pc'>
    {{ pc.parent_name }}
    <br>
    Enter parent_name <input ng-model='pc.parent_name'/>
    <br>
    <button ng-click='pc.change_parent_name()'>change parent_name</button>

    <div ng-controller='child_controller as cc'>
        <div ng-repeat='item in pc.myarray' style='border:1px solid #ccc; margin:20px;'>
            Item = {{ item }}
            <br>
            <button ng-click='cc.change_item_name($index)'>change item name</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

var app = angular.module('app',[]);

function parent_controller(){
    var self = this;
    window.s = self; // For debugging

    self.myarray = ['a','b','c'];

    self.change_parent_name = function () {
        self.parent_name = 'changed!!';
    }
}
app.controller('parent_controller',[parent_controller]);

function child_controller() {
    var self = this;    
    window.cs = self; // For debugging

    parent_controller.apply(self, arguments);

    self.change_item_name = function(index){
        console.log(index);
        self.myarray[index] = 'changed';
    }

}
app.controller('child_controller',[child_controller]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the array has primitive string type, pass in the parent array and index into the child controller function and it should work fine.

```
 self.change_item_name = function(items, index){
        console.log(index);
        items[index] = 'changed';
    }
```

And the html changes to:

`<button ng-click='cc.change_item_name(pc.myarray,$index)'>change item name</button>`

Comment: Ahh dang it. I simplified my example down and forgot about reference vs value. Making the changes you mentioned allow one button to change the item name, but pressing the other buttons gives Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]. Do you know why it would do that? I also tried changing myarray to hold objects instead of strings (which is more what I am interested in) but it doesn't work at all (no dupe error though :-P)

Comment: The dup error comes because ng-repeat need to uniquely identify elements, for objects it does it by adding a key to them.

Comment: If you use object then it should work. How are you using object based approach.

Comment: Ahh yeah, of course. self.myarray = [
  {'a':1},
  {'b':2},
  {'c':3}
 ];  ....and.....  self.change_item_name = function(index){
        console.log(index);
        self.myarray[index] = {'changed': 999};
    }

Comment: myarray as i understand is defined on parent controller so you cannot get it from child. try `function(array,index) { array[index]={...};`

Comment: Ahh, okay. That's disappointing. I thought nesting controllers meant a child inherits its parent's scope

Comment: Scopes are inherited, not controllers. The controller gets added to the parent scope, so you maybe able to access the parent, buy why would you want to do that and create unnecessary dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off putting the child controller on the ng-repeat, and then using that to update the parent controller. $scope.$apply is not necessary. If you want to update the parent controller from the controller code, you are better off using a service to communicate between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the data source from the parent controller to a service and injecting that service into both controllers allows them to access the same data. [[AngularJS API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)]

This example does that and adds a third controller to highlight the extent to which the data is shared across controllers.

ctrl_3 below also shows how $scope can be accessed using `controller as` syntax. $scope is only used for the console.log part - it isn't used for this service approach.

```
<html ng-app='app'>
<body ng-controller='a_controller as ctrl_1'>
    {{ ctrl_1.parent_name }}
    <br>
    Enter parent_name <input ng-model='ctrl_1.parent_name'/>
    <br>
    <button ng-click='ctrl_1.change_parent_name()'>change parent_name</button>

    <div><strong>ctrl_2</strong></div>
    <div ng-controller='a_controller as ctrl_2'>
        <div ng-repeat='item in ctrl_2.myarray' style='border:1px solid #ccc; margin:20px;'>
            Item = {{ item }}
            <br>
            <button ng-click='ctrl_2.change_item_name(ctrl_2.myarray, $index)'>change item name</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- an extra repeat of the myarray, this time using ctrl_1 for the repeat of myarray but ctrl_3 as the controller, just to show it all ties back to the same data source -->
    <hr>
    <div><strong>ctrl_3</strong></div>
    <div ng-controller='a_controller as ctrl_3'>
        <div ng-repeat='item in ctrl_1.myarray' style='border:1px solid #ccc; margin:20px;'>
            Item = {{ item }}
            <br>
            <button ng-click='ctrl_3.change_item_name(ctrl_3.myarray, $index)'>change item name</button>
        </div>
    </div>


<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>

angular.module('app',[])
.factory('DataService', [function() {
    data = [ {'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3} ];

    return {
        myarray : data
    }
}])
.controller('a_controller', ['DataService', '$scope', function(DataService, $scope) {
    var self = this;
    window.s = self; // For debugging
    console.log($scope);

    self.myarray = DataService.myarray;

    self.change_parent_name = function () {
        self.parent_name = 'changed!!';
    }

    self.change_item_name = function(array,index){ 
        array[index] = {'changed': 999}; 
    }
}]);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```